# Variance of $X + \alpha^\top Y$ where $X$ is a scalar random variable and $Y$ is a random vector

Tags: probability, variance, multivariate-analysis, expected-value, covariance

Consider a scalar random variable $X\in\mathbb{R}$, a vector random variable $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a constant (non-random) vector $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to compute
$$
\mathbb{V}[X + \alpha^\top Y]
$$
but I can't find any material on this. I have checked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) and in various lecture notes.

## Attempt

$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{V}[X + \alpha^\top Y]
&= \mathbb{V}[X] + \alpha^\top\mathbb{V}[Y]\alpha + 2\text{Cov}(X, Y)\alpha
\end{align}
$$
However things here get confusing because $\mathbb{V}[Y]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the covariance seems weird. Is it a vector in this context?
$$
\begin{align}
    \text{Cov}(X, Y) 
    &= \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])^\top)
\end{align}
$$
where here $X - \mathbb{E}[X]$ is a scalar and $Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]$ is a vector..

Comment: $X+\alpha^\prime Y$ is explicitly a linear combination of random variables with coefficients $1,\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n.$ If it helps, write $Z = (X, Y^\prime)^\prime$ (an $n+1$-vector) and let $\beta = (1,\alpha^\prime)^\prime,$ so that $X+\alpha^\prime Y = \beta^\prime Z$ and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculation is actually correct.  To clarify, by convention, $Y$ and $\alpha$ are **column** vectors, so that $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = E[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])^\top]$ is a **row** vector, after multiplying with the column vector $\alpha$, $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)\alpha$ becomes a scalar, as expected.